# How to insertTable from sheet after specific text in google docs using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have got this code from Tanaike. It works but I don't understand the `if` statement.

Can someone explain this to me?

```
    var body = somedoc.getBody(); 
    var range = body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#"); 
    var ele = range.getElement(); 

    if (ele.getParent().getParent().getType() === DocumentApp.ElementType.BODY_SECTION) { 
      var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());
      body.insertTable(offset + 1, data);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the rest of your code and question - what the code snippet does is to find a the text "PLACEHOLDER" in your document and to insert a table into the same `StructuralElement` as the one containing the `Paragraph` with your text.

### It is useful to visualize the [structure of a Google Docs document](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/structure)

[image]

[image]

### In your case

- The `if` statement verifies either the parent of the parent of `ele` is a `BodySection`
- If the condition is fulfilled, it means that `ele` is a `ParagraphElement`
- It also means that the parent of `ele` is a `Paragraph`
- All `StructuralElements` have a `childIndex`
- `var offset = body.getChildIndex(ele.getParent());` finds the `childIndex` of the `Paragraph` that contains `ele`
- The inserted `table` will have an index one higher than the `Paragraph`, this means that it will be inserted directly after the `Paragraph`